# Store json data in file when connection between mqtt client and broker lost

Tags: python, json, database, serialization, mqtt

I have mqtt client which publishing some messages to broker.

The message is like below

```
{
    "message": {
        "body": {
            "software_sub_version": "O", 
            "software_version": 1.25, 
            "hardware_id": 17, 
            "machine_id": 39
        }, 
        "header": {
            "Machine_name": "MY_MACHINE", 
            "message_type": "machine_data", 
            "message_version": "1.0", 
            "publish_time": "2017-02-22T06:44:27.281644+00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

While publishing the message, I am checking if connection with broker is there or not, if it is not there I am storing the message to file using below code.

```
def mqtt_publish():
   if no_connection:
       store_json_data()
   else:
       send_msg()
```

I also need to send stored msg one by one to broker.

```
while True:
    if stored_msg_present:
         send_stored_msg_to_broker()
```

What should be the best way to do this.
Is it good to use database like tinydb for this.
But I am not able retrieve element from tinydb data base.

Answer (score 0):

Save to database or file or just save in memory is up to you and your environment.

If the connection is very rarely to connect and usually disconnect for a long time, then save to database or file is easier to save memory. But if your messages are less, it is still ok to just save in memory. (e.g. a queue or a list)

If the connection is very stable and rare to disconnect, and will recover in short time (e.g. several seconds), then save to memory may not be a bad choice. But if your messages grows very fast (e.g. thousands of messages per second), then keep them all in memory may not be a good choice.

Comparison between file and database, if you have to hold a lots of data, maybe multithread programing to access them, or need to query them to choose which one to upload first, then database will be easier to handle. If your data is simple and less, you may easier handle them with files.

Environment is another consideration, if you use some low quality chip, maybe you should consider their performance or stability. (e.g. lack of memory or disk full)

Finally is the data importance. If your memory and disk is short, data is not so important to miss some, maybe you can just discard them, save your effort to handle them. It's just up to you.